# Why do you not want to make this trip?

Tags: pattern

From Hiroshima, Japan to Nantucket, Massachusetts.

Try to solve this without Google.

Comment: This is more of a joke than a puzzle. If you don't already know the relevant info, you can't really solve it. Why not let people Google -- it at least gives them a chance?

Comment: I wouldn't want to make that trip because it is a damn long flight.

Comment: @xnor It's just so obvious if you google the airports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is:

> the airport codes are HIJ ACK
>
>  Yes, I've heard this one before ;-)